# Why does data binding break in OneWay mode?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding-mode

Here's a little XAML fragment. You will see

```
<StackPanel>
     <TextBox x:Name="txtValue">250</TextBox>
     <Slider x:Name="slide" 
             Value="{Binding ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, 
                             Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Minimum="0" Maximum="500"></Slider>
</StackPanel>
```

1. when you change the textbox value, the slider updates
2. If you change the slider value explicitly, the previous behavior breaks a.k.a. stops working.

If I remove the `Mode=OneWay` set directive, (defaults to two-way) everything works perfectly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 13):

Use `mode=TwoWay` and set the `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`.

Answer (score 2):

Your data binding is not broken but deactivated (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism):

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 75 : BindingExpression (hash=52697953): Deactivate
System.Windows.Data Warning: 99 : BindingExpression (hash=52697953): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 59 : BindingExpression (hash=52697953): Detach
```

Setting the trace level to high will produce this message in the VS output window in case you move the slider:

```
<Slider xmlns:trace="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
        Value="{Binding trace:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High,
            ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Minimum="0" Maximum="500"></Slider>
```

Comment: Why does it detach? It kind of defeats the purpose of one-way binding if doing something like moving the thumb on the bound control deactivates or unhooks the binding. By broken, I meant the expected behavior isn't seen anymore.

Comment: That's the way it is implemented :-(
If it does not meet your needs don't use WPF data binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a control which inherits from `Slider`, then override the `Value` property and use [`DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue) when changing the value rather than [`DependencyOpbject.SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue), then your databindings will be preserved when changing the values programmatically.

Sorry this isn't particularly exhaustive, will update this answer to include a basic implementation of this at a later date.

Alternatively, a `UserControl` which contains both the textbox and the slider would make for a very reusable implementation, in which you could bind them both to the same custom dependencyproperty, make the binding oneway, hijack the valuechanged event of the slider, set `e.Handled = true`, and call the `SetCurrentValue` function from that.